# "/" Raiz do site em PHP

Tags: php, virtualhost, apache, httpd

Amigos desculpa se estou repetindo alguma pergunta aqui, mas eu busquei e não encontrei especificamente meu problema, então vamos lá.

Fiz um curso em videaula, e criei um site em PHP no qual, na minha maquina (windows 10 com Xamp) eu editei o arquivo HOSTS, criei um hostvirtual apontando para pasta onde o site está (c:/xamp/htdocs/meusite).

Agora eu fiz uma VM com o CENTOS7, instalei apache (HTTPD), movi os meus arquivos e banco de dados, etc.. inclusive minha .HTACCESS.

Resumo da brincadeira, na minha aplicação eu referencio minhas rotas com base na raiz:

"\caminho"

No meu windows ele intende a raiz assim 
**"c:\xamp\htdocs\meusite\"**

NO CENTOS ele entende a raiz como sendo a raiz do sistema 
**"\"**

quando do um include por exemplo 
include "\css\estil.css" 
no windows ele encontra o arquivo sem problemas "C:\xamp\htdocs\meusite\css\estilo.css"

no CENTOS ele não encontra o arquivo pois procura em:
"\css\estilo.css"
o correto era procurar em 
"\var\www\html\meusite\css\estilo.css";

Acho que é isso, eu preciso aprender uma maneira de que quando eu der um "\" no php ele entenda que não é a "\" do sistema e sim uma a pasta "\var\www\html\meusite"

Comment: Você deve configurar o VHOST apontando para a pasta onde está seu site.

Comment: Sim. Quado abro o meu servidor o nome dele é srvintra, ele já cai na minha pasta, certinho.

Comment: Detalhe, via navegador, o apache redireciona para pasta da minha aplicação, só que via PHP ele busca na raiz do sistema

Answer (score -2):

Verifique no apache a configuração do DocumentRoot
No seu caso deve ter a seguinte configuração, para o apache2.4

```
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/meusite
<Directory "/var/www/html/meusite">
        AllowOverride all
        # New directive needed in Apache 2.4.3:
        Require all granted
</Directory>
```